# The issue with two left join in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

Currently I have three datasets

```
table 1:
| day | spend | id |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2023-02-02   | 2.4   | 1 |

table 2:
| day | name | id |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2023-02-03   | Apple   | 1 |
| 2023-02-06   | Banana   | 2 |

table 3:
| prev_day | prev_name | prev_id |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2023-02-02   | Apple   | 1 |
| 2023-02-05   | Banana   | 2 |

table1
  .join(table2, table1("id") === table2("id") && table1("day") === table2("day"), "left")
  .join(table3, table1("id") === table3("prev_id") && table1("day") === table3("prev_day"), "left")
  .select(table1("day"), table1("spend"), table1("id"), table2("name").as("name1"), table3("prev_name").as("name2"))

result:
| day | spend | id | name1 | name2 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2023-02-02   | 2.4   | 1 | null | null |
```

But when I remove the previous join, I will get the correct result:

```
table1
  .join(table3, table1("id") === table3("prev_id") && table1("day") === table3("prev_day"), "left")
  .select(table1("day"), table1("spend"), table1("id"), table3("prev_name").as("name2"))

result:
| day | spend | id | name2 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2023-02-02   | 2.4   | 1 | Apple |
```

Does any one know what's going wrong with that?

I don't know how to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the date of table 1 has one day more than that of table3 so that the join will not fit, subtracting one day of table1 day will do the trick

```
table1
  .join(table2, table1("id") === table2("id") && table1("day") === table2("day"), "left")
  .join(table3, table1("id") === table3("prev_id") &&  date_sub(table1("day"),1)  === table3("prev_day"), "left")
  .select(table1("day"), table1("spend"), table1("id"), table2("name").as("name1"), table3("prev_name").as("name2"))
```